Unable to connect to AD using Java client with digest-md5, ssl enabled and qop auth-int/conf when channel binding and signing are required in LDAP
We are trying to connect to LDAP using below sample java code.
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;
import java.util.Hashtable;
public class LDAPBindSSLExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String ldapURL = "ldaps://machine.domain.com:636";
        String username = "username"; // without @domain
        String domainName = "domain.com";
        String password = "password";
        String timeout = "5000";
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put("java.naming.security.sasl.realm", domainName);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "DIGEST-MD5");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
        env.put("javax.security.sasl.qop", "auth");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapURL);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "ignore");
        env.put("java.naming.ldap.version", "3");
        env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.tls.cbtype", "tls-server-end-point");
        env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool", "true");
        env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", timeout);
        LdapContext ctx = null;
        try {
            ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
            System.out.println("Bind successful");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } 
        finally {
            if (ctx!=null) {
                ctx.close();
            }
        }
    }
}

We are encountering an error when connecting to an LDAP server using the Java code (Java 17) with certain Active Directory registry settings. Specifically, when we set the following registry entries as per the Microsoft Guide: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/2020-2023-and-2024-ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirements-for-windows-kb4520412-ef185fb8-00f7-167d-744c-f299a66fc00a
LdapEnforceChannelBinding=2
ldapserverintegrity=2
We receive the following error message: LDAP: error code 49 - 80090346: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906AC, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 80090346, v4563
Could you please assist us in resolving this issue?
However, when we set LdapEnforceChannelBinding=1 (while keeping ldapserverintegrity=2), the connection is successful.
Additionally, with both LdapEnforceChannelBinding=2 and ldapserverintegrity=2, we can connect to the non-SSL LDAP URL "ldap://machine.domain.com:389".
We have validated that certificate is trusted in keystore and latest openjdk-17 is being used.
